# Inserting multiple elements using jquery .html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently using jquery `.html` for DOM insertion. Is there a way I can insert multiple elements?

So far I have tried using `&&` or even using a comma inserting multiple elements but none of them seems to be feasible. Separating it would also likely not work.

```
$('#header .aim-breadcrumbs').html($('.layout-container .region-breadcrumb') && $('#header .aim-nav .connect'));

$('#header .aim-breadcrumbs').html($('.layout-container .region-breadcrumb', '#header .aim-nav .connect');
```

---

```
$('#header .aim-breadcrumbs').html($('.layout-container .region-breadcrumb');

$('#header .aim-breadcrumbs').html($('#header .aim-nav .connect');
```

Comment: I think you want `.append()` not `.html()`, and you need to specify elements, not just a list of classes and/or IDs

Comment: `.html()` will override the previous one if you want multiple then this is not the correct to use. try `.append()`

Comment: use .append() → check this link: https://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: If you want to use the same div for multiple things .html would be better because you don't need to clear the contents before appending.

Comment: Are you trying to move existing elements around, or insert/add new elements to the page?

Answer (score 3):

You are really close. You just need to put the comma inside your selector string. Don't use two strings.

```
$('#header .aim-breadcrumbs').html($('.layout-container .region-breadcrumb, #header .aim-nav .connect'));
```

This will work, but as everyone is already shouting, `.append` is the typical way of doing this.

```
$('#header .aim-breadcrumbs').append($('.layout-container .region-breadcrumb, #header .aim-nav .connect'));
```

Comment: Exactly what kind of magical unicorn elements will this add to the document? You can't just list classes and IDs and no actual elements and try to append them to something. You're also missing closing parenthesis.

Comment: I fixed the parenthesis. It's not just adding random classes. If you pass a jquery object like `$(.selector)`, it will move or copy that element for you, depending on the method you use.

Comment: Thank you for that insights, wasn't aware that inserting a comma inside the string would be valid